# What does "they" in "they don't" refer to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

On their way to a beach on a car , Captain Boomerang sitting face to face with Savant:

> Captain Boomerang: We're in a butcher's freezer, Harls, surrounded by dead hogs
> hangin' on hooks. Only **they** don't know it yet.

What does "they" in "they don't" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They" refers to the other occupants of the car.

> Captain Boomerang: *We're in a butcher's freezer, Harls, surrounded by dead hogs hangin' on hooks. Only they don't know it yet.*

could just as easily be rewritten as

> **Captain Boomerang:** *We're [basically dead], Harls, surrounded by [other dead people]. Only the [other people around us] don't know [it] yet.*